# What is a good way of identifying which versions of artifacts are currently used in production?

Tags: svn, deployment, version-control, dev-to-production

We are using Subversion to develop artifacts we use internally. When a tag is created and tested for an artifact, it goes to production. Let's says version `1.3.5` of an artifact goes live. Developers do not have access to production servers directly, only sysadmins can know what exact version is currently used in production.

Let's now say there is a quick fix to make on the version that is currently in production, `1.3.5`. Developers should take the associated `1.3.5` tag and create a `1.3.5-fix` branch from it and this will lead to a `1.3.6` tag. But how do they know the version `1.3.5` is the one used in production, the one to branch from? What are the recommended ways of listing the versions of artifacts used in production in a company?

It won't necessarily be the latest tag that will represent the production. Maybe a severe bug has been found in production (bug not found during the QA phase) and the live version has been downgraded to the previous version/tag.

Are there softwares or some kind of patterns to list "which versions are currently used in an environment"? I know *communication* can be an answer but I would prefere something formal and automated.

Answer (score 3):

Change your build process to create an install package for your target platform.

For example if deploying to Redhat Linux creating an RPM package for your software has two important advantages:

1. Repository technology for distributing binaries
2. OS provides an installer for your software ("yum" command)
3. OS maintains a software inventory. The "rpm" command can tell you which version is installed.

Comment: I agree, but developers do not have access to the production servers.

Comment: @electrotype It's common for applications to have an "About" option on their UI, listing the exact version. For web applications the same functionality is delivered using a "/version" URL. Lots of ways to do this easily.

Comment: Why do your developers need access to the production servers to create an install package for it?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way (although done by hand, not automated): when you are about to create a tag (eg. `1.3.5`) you will change part of the code which is holding version info string (in .NET, that can be [AssemblyInfo.cs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class). Commit the code and create a tag `1.3.5`. This version info string is then read by the code that can be displayed in footer of your app (if you are running a web site), or you can retrieve it via dedicated web method (if you are running web service). Similar applies to others types of apps.

If you are using [AssemblyInfo.cs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will read it like this:

```
string version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Now it's easy to anybody to see which software version is currently running.

Comment: This. As Ivan has noted exposing the version number is going to be dependent on your tools and technology.  Just wanted to note the footer on this site - it tells you the version of the app.